Typescript importing file but get error ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND
I have two projects in one dir with the following file structure:

I want to use code from recommender project in the data_generation project. So I have added the following lines in the tsconfig files of the projects
recommender/tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "outDir": "bin",
    "lib": [
      "ESNext",
      "DOM"
    ],
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "moduleDetection": "force",
    "strict": true,
    "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,
    "disableSizeLimit": true,
    "exactOptionalPropertyTypes": true,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "moduleResolution": "Bundler",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationMap": true,
    "composite": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "references": []
}

data_generation/tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "outDir": "bin",
    "lib": [
      "ESNext",
      "DOM",
    ],
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "moduleDetection": "force",
    "strict": true,
    "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,
    "disableSizeLimit": true,
    "exactOptionalPropertyTypes": true,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "moduleResolution": "Bundler",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationMap": true,
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "../recommender",
    }
  ]
}

Now, for example if want to use types I created on the recommender project, it works just fine:
data_generation/src/data/teams.ts
import { Team } from "../../../recommender/src/models/team.js";
export const teams: Team[] = [
    { name: `Team A` },
    { name: `Team B` },
    { name: `Team C` },
    { name: `Team D` },
    { name: `Team E` },
    { name: `Team F` },
    { name: `Team G` },
];

printing all the exported code above works:

Now here comes the problem. When I try to import code and not just types, somehow it doesn't run.
Trying to import class UUID which is in recommend/src/functionality/uuid.ts:
data_generation/src/functionality/event_generator_engine.ts:
import { UUID } from "../../../recommender/src/functionality/uuid.js";

If I then build the recommender project with tsc -b and then build the data_generation project with tsc -b I get the following error when I call anything from the file above:

